# how to develop for am Map in visual studio

Tags: apache-flex, visual-studio-2008, google-maps, flash-builder

i want  to make a asp.net website that has amMap in it (http://flex.ammap.com/download), now for that i installed Flex plug-in in VS 2008 Ensemble Tofino (http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml) now the part where i am stuck is how to include amMap API in flex plugin in VS, for flash builder its trivial (http://blog.amcharts.com/2010/11/ammap-for-flex-tutorials-part-1-basic.html).

Appreciate any help

P.S: Dont want to develop in flash builder coz i only have its trial version and dont want to use any map except am Map because of limitaions of other such as google map that wont zoom or pan

Comment: You need to add the SWC to the library path.  If a library path is not easily exposed via Tofino; you should be able to do so as a command line argument.  Tofino product page said SWCs are supported; but doesn't seem to show how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Ensemble Tofino Plugin for VS, Just follow these steps to get started :

1. Create Flex 4 Project in Visual Studio.
2. Now you need to add the ammap component, in the solution explorer, right click on references and browse and add "amMapFB4.swc" which you would have downloaded from the ammap flex map api.
3. Lets also import a map here so we can load it in the component later - right click on maps folder and add existing item, browse to the folder where you have put the ammap api, find "world.swf" in "build" folder and add to project.
4. Now open your main.mxml file and enter the following code

```
   <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
           [Bindable]
          [Embed(source="../assets/maps/world.swf")]
           private var _world:Class;            
       ]]>
 </fx:Script>

 <ammap:AmMap>
     <ammap:dataSets>
       <ammap:DataSet
             mapClass="{_world}">
        </ammap:DataSet>
      </ammap:dataSets>
  </ammap:AmMap>
```

make Sure you set the Path correctly in the "[Embed(source="../assets/maps/world.swf")]" line.

Run it and the world map should load up in your browser.

Comment: im not sure why byt stackoverflow isnt showing the first few lines of the code, well here they are :
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"  xmlns:ammap="http://www.ammap.com/com_internal">

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure visual studio cannot compile Flex, so you're SOL.  What you can do is download the Flex SDK and use the included mxmlc compiler to compile your code.  You can use any kind of text editor to modify the code.  I don't see why exactly it's a problem with coding in Flash Builder trial, but I digress.  If you're developing on Windows, you can always download FlashDevelop; it's free and can compile Flex.

Comment: visual studio can compile flex, pretty sure of tht

Comment: -1 for not reading the question.  There are two Visual Studio Plugins for Flex; and one was mentioned in the original post.  The other VS Plugin is named Amethyst ( http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/amethyst-ide/Amethyst-Product-Page ).